# Setting a GuildMembers Nickname

Tags: discord, dsharp+

new here. I utilize DSharp for writing my first Discord Bot. I can’t for the life of me seem to figure out how to set the GuildMembers Nickname. I am able to get it, however I can’t figure out how to set it. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried thus far?

Comment: Hi! Yes, essentially I have used something along the lines of this: DiscordMember discMember = ctx.Client.Member and then later attempted assigning to it with: discMember.Nickname = “string”; but the problem is, that property is a read only field is it it just used to get; the nickname.